Position/placement of coconut in kalash
What are the benefits of keeping coconut in kalash in different positions/placements?
For example, Shikha of coconut facing upwards, towards the worshipper, against the worshipper and so on.
Sri Sri Shankaracharya of Badari has explained in this video but looking for scriptural references to this.
